# Securing package name from attacks

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

My application is being attacked by a rival company by suggesting an uninstall after checking installed apps(package name) in user device. I want to find a way to hide my package name or to remove it from the list of installed applications on the user so that the attack from the rival company wont be initiated.
Note. most of my users have android level below API 30 thus consider that when suggesting solutions

Comment: Suggesting to uninstall a given app is kind of a dick-move by your rival, but at the end of the day they can't do it without user interaction. So just make sure that your users don't *want* to uninstall your app and they won't.

Comment: what's an "android level below API 30" and how do I get one? this is so exciting!

Comment: Trying to hide your app would in my opinion confirm your opponents impression that uninstalling the app would be wise. You need to go the opposite way, to demonstrate that having your app is a good idea. I mean, it is not that your app could be considered malicious by any user who is aware of it being on their phone. Could it?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to find a way to hide my package name or to remove it from the list of installed applications on the user

Fortunately, that is not possible, for security reasons.

Comment: What are my possible options?

Comment: @Eyosiyas: That is a fine question for your firm's attorney.